# How to fix reading order panel (Z-order) that reads continuous structural elements as a single one

Tags: java, pdfbox

[image: tag structures] [image: reading order panel] [image: content panel]
Here see the tags image first six tags are paragraph, then header and then again three more paragraph tag. Same things coming in content panel i.e first six and last three paragraph tag and then header, annotation as well. But if you look into reading order panel image then first six paragraph coming as a single reading order and last three paragraph is also coming as single reading order and this is main problem that I am facing.

Also if page has all tens paragraph then its reading order consider as a single reading order.
So, whole summary is that if page has continuous similar structural elements, then it reads as a single structural element inside the reading order. (Structure elements may be headers, list, paragraph.)

Below is code logic for drawing text into content stream of current page.
**TextPositionsInfo** list contain whole texts of a particular structural element(i.e paragraph, headers ,lists) information of textPosition after extracting text using PDFTextStripper class.

```
public class TextPositionsInfo {
    public String unicode;
    public float fontSize;
    public String fontName;
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float width;
    public float height;
    public Matrix textMatrix;
}
```

```
private PDPageContentStream currentContentStream;
private COSDictionary currentMarkedContentDictionary;
private int mcid = 1;

private PDStructureElement addTextCharByChar(List<TextPositionsInfo> textinfoList, String elementType, PDPage currentPage,
    PDStructureElement Parent) throws IOException {
    PDResources res = currentPage.getResources();
    PDStructureElement currParent = null;
    currentContentStream.beginText(); 
    if (elementType.toLowerCase().equals("h2")) {
        beginMarkedConent(COSName.H);
        for(TextPositionsInfo textInfo : textinfoList) {
            PDFont font = getFonts(res, textInfo.fontName);
            if(font != null) {
                currentContentStream.setFont(font, 1);
                Matrix _tm = textInfo.textMatrix;
                currentContentStream.setTextMatrix(_tm);
                currentContentStream.showText(textInfo.unicode);
            }
        }
        currentContentStream.endMarkedContent();
        currParent = addStructEleToStructEleTree(elementType,
                Parent,currentPage, COSName.H);
        
    } else if (elementType.toLowerCase().equals("p"))  {
        beginMarkedConent(COSName.P);
        for(TextPositionsInfo textInfo : textinfoList) {
            PDFont font = getFonts(res, textInfo.fontName);
            if(font != null) {
                currentContentStream.setFont(font, 1);
                currentContentStream.setTextMatrix(textInfo.textMatrix);
                currentContentStream.showText(textInfo.unicode);
            }
        }
        currParent = addStructEleToStructEleTree(elementType,
                Parent,currentPage, COSName.P);
        currentContentStream.endMarkedContent();
        
    }
    currentContentStream.endText();
    return currParent;
}
```

```
private PDStructureElement addStructEleToStructEleTree(String elementtype,
    PDStructureElement Parent,PDPage currentPage, COSName name) {
    PDStructureElement StructEle = new PDStructureElement(elementtype, Parent);
    StructEle.setPage(currentPage);
    PDMarkedContent markedContent = new PDMarkedContent(name, currentMarkedContentDictionary);
    StructEle.appendKid(markedContent);
    Parent.appendKid(StructEle);
    return StructEle;
}
```

```
private COSDictionary beginMarkedConent(COSName name) throws IOException {
    currentMarkedContentDictionary = new COSDictionary();
    currentMarkedContentDictionary.setInt(COSName.MCID, mcid);
    mcid++;
    currentContentStream.beginMarkedContent(name, 
           PDPropertyList.create(currentMarkedContentDictionary));
    return currentMarkedContentDictionary;
}
```

So, please help me where things are going wrong.

Comment: hi @mkl  can you help me on this please.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not my field of expertise; I neither really understand what your code is doing (it's not really self-contained) nor do I understand the issue (your screen shots don't tell what really is inside the PDF). If you need help, please provide enough code and the inputs to reproduce the issue, and also an example result PDF for analysis. Also this feels quite complex, beyond the scope of a stack overflow question, but with more simplified examples that may change.

Comment: Thanks @mkl yeah I know playing with content panel and reading order panel (Z-order) is tough one.  I have tried to make it simpler . Please look into it again.

Comment: @mkl I making it more simpler . Please look into this file [https://acrobat.adobe.com/link/review?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:528c049f-db5b-3f37-a04d-71eb67301a40 ] . See the difference in content panel container and reading order panel container as I mentioned above.